# This DC Motor shouldn't have any current while I'm not pressing the button (pin 7 is LOW) but it has. (When I'm pressing the button its as intended)

Tags: motor, voltage

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to find the problem, and I believe its not about the code but I will give you the code nevertheless.

```cpp
const int pinOFswitch = 4;  
const int motor_3 = 7;
const int pushbtn = 5;  

void setup( ) {  
  pinMode(pinOFswitch, INPUT);    
  pinMode(motor_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pushbtn, INPUT);  
   
}  
void loop( )   
{  
  byte pbtn;
  pbtn = digitalRead(pushbtn);
  while(pbtn == HIGH){
    int ValueOFswitch;
    ValueOFswitch = digitalRead(pinOFswitch);  
    if (ValueOFswitch == HIGH){  
        digitalWrite(motor_3, LOW);
        pbtn = digitalRead(pushbtn);
    }   
    else   
    {  
        digitalWrite(motor_3, HIGH);
        pbtn = digitalRead(pushbtn);
    }
  }
        digitalWrite(motor_3, LOW);
}
```

Comment: It seems, that you are using an NPN transistor as high side switch (on the Vcc site of the motor). Try connecting the NPN transistor as low side switch (between the motor and ground).

Comment: `When I'm pressing the button its as intended` ... how do you know know this? ... maybe the button does not even work

Comment: Inverted polarity of the 18V motor supply? The voltage on the motor looks like 18V minus Veb breakdown voltage ~= 12V

Comment: This would benefit from a proper schematic, but it looks like the GND (-) of your motor is not connected to the GND of Arduino, but instead the +9 V going into the Arduino and the +18V feeding the motor are connected. Are you sure that's what you intended?